# Pytorch: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'function'

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to calculate Intersection over Union (IOU) score. Here's my code implementation, which works fine.

```
def IoU(predict: torch.Tensor, target: torch.Tensor):

    i = (predict & target).float().sum()
    u = (predict | target).float().sum()
    x = i/u
    IOU = x.item()

    return IoU
```

But when I run my unit test:

```
def test_IoU1():
    pred = torch.tensor([[1, 0], [1, 0]])
    target = torch.tensor([[1, 0], [1, 1]])
    
    iou = IoU(pred,target)
    
    assert 0.66 <= iou
    assert iou <= 2/3
```

I get:

```
 TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'function'
```

[image]

How do I fix this without changing anything on the unit test? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function

```py
def IoU(predict: torch.Tensor, target: torch.Tensor):

    i = (predict & target).float().sum()
    u = (predict | target).float().sum()
    x = i/u
    IOU = x.item()
    
    return IoU
```

You are returning `IoU` which is the name of function, I suppose you need to return `IOU`. So the correct way would be -

```py
def IoU(predict: torch.Tensor, target: torch.Tensor):

    i = (predict & target).float().sum()
    u = (predict | target).float().sum()
    x = i/u
    IOU = x.item()
    
    return IOU
```